# Android how to send touch event coordinates to another screen of different size and denisty and keep it?

Tags: android, canvas, motionevent

So I will explain this as simple as possible:

I am trying to make a 2d online game. I want to start somewhere, so consider we have two devices A and B of different screen sizes, now when user1 touches somewhere on the screen of device A, I want to let user2 on device B to know exaclty where user1 touched.

**update:**

Okay so if I for example get the coordinates in device A like this:

```
float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY():
```

and then I send them to a device of smaller screen how can I guarantee that they will render in the same place that I touched them in device A?

Answer (score 0):

You may suppose **MVC** (Model-View-Control) structure or something.

You can use an MVC-Model class of **World** coordinates that holds a logical space.

For the MVC-View class of **Display**, a World coordinates will be converted to a physical coordinates of device's display called **Viewport**.

When you get an input (MVC-Control) of physical coordinates, it will be converted to the World ones.

Thus you can hold World coordinates separated from physical ones of different devices.

There are many resources about Window to Viewport coordinate transformation on the Internet.

For example: [Computer Graphics Window to Viewport Co-ordinate Transformation](https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-graphics-window-to-viewport-co-ordinate-transformation)

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you please see my update of my question, thanks.

Comment: @SomeUser Please refer some Internet resources for further information.

Answer (score 0):

just divide the A's touch-x with A's screen width, touch-y with A's screen height. Then at the receiving side B's side get the x and multiply with B's screen width and get y and multiply with B's screen height.

that should work